# How links come up, when an autoneg disabled FE port is connected to Autoneg enabled 10/100/1G port

Tags: ethernet, layer1, autonegotiation, ieee-802.3x

I was just learning about auto-negotiation and got some doubts.

As per the standard 802.3 clause 28, 10BASE-T ports transmits LIT or NLP pulses to make the link UP.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonegotiation

Also when 10/100/1G (Auto-neg enabled) port is connected to 10M FD (auto-neg disabled) port, FLP from Auto-neg port and NLP from Auto-neg disable port will be transmitted, result is 10M HD and 10M FD respectively.

1. What will happen when 10/100/1G (Auto-neg enabled) port is connected to 100M FD (auto-neg disabled) port ?
2. Does 100M port use the same LIT/NLP ?
3. What signaling method does 100M port use when 2 FE ports (Autoneg disabled) are connected to each other  ?

Thanks in advance for reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Usually the port comes up - due to lack of autonegotiation, the auto side will choose half duplex, resulting in a duplex mismatch.
2. Fast Ethernet uses "fast link pulses", an expanded scheme.
3. Autoneg disabled on both sides leaves only the carrier (pause symbols) to detect the link. FDX/HDX will be as set up, potentially mismatching.

Comment: So autoneg enabled port will transmits FLP s, and autoneg disabled port will transmit pause symbols. And when both ports autoneg is disabled, both transmits pause symbols. Can u just explain little more on these 'pause symbols' ? or is there any docs which i can read ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should check IEEE 802.3 itself: http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/browse/standards/get-program/page/series?id=68 For FE, you need Section 2, Clauses 22, 28 and especially 24.3.4.3-4 for non-autoneg links.

Answer (score 0):

Cisco has a document, [*Troubleshooting Cisco Catalyst Switches to NIC Compatibility Issues*](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/switches/catalyst-6500-series-switches/17053-46.html), that describes this, that includes a table that tells you what happens at various settings.

A duplex mismatch usually occurs when on side of a link is set to auto-negotiate, but the other side of the link is set to a fixed speed. When this is the case, the side set to auto-negotiate cannot negotiate. It will detect the fixed speed, and it will default to the duplex for the speed (half duplex for 10 or 100 Mbps).

A duplex mismatch will cause a lot of input errors, collisions, runt, giants, etc. Your throughput will be horrendous. Things will seem to work very slowly.